# String subscript out of range error "C++"

Tags: c++

This program takes a text file and changes each word into pig Latin. I have gotten everything to work but continue to get the error "subscript out of range". I have tried to change many things but cant get it to go away. Can someone explain why I am getting this error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>   
#include <iomanip>  
using namespace std;

void piglatin ( string word[], string temp, ifstream & in, int num);

int main()
{
    string word[300];
    string original[300];
    string temp;
    ifstream in;
    int i=0,
        j=0,
        x=0,
        par=0,
        length=0;

    in.open("text.txt");

    if (in.is_open()) {       //Checks if file is open
        cout << "\nFile is open....\n\n\n";
    } else {
        cout << "Error: Failed to open!\n";       
        cout << "Exiting program\n";
        exit(-1);
    }
    cout<<"Original text\n\n";

    do {//Continues while loop until no more input. 
        in >> original[x];
        cout << original[x] << " ";
        x++;
        par = par + x;
    } while (!in.eof());

    cout<<"\n\n";
    cout<<"Pig Latin\n\n";
    piglatin(original,temp,in,par);

    return 0;
}

void piglatin ( string word[], string temp, ifstream & in, int num)
{
    int i=0, length, j=0,a=0;
    for(j = 0; j < num; j++) {
        string str (word[j]);
        length = str.size();
        temp[0] = word[j][0];

        if ((temp[0] == 'a') ||
            (temp[0] == 'e') ||
            (temp[0] == 'i') ||
            (temp[0] == 'o') ||
            (temp[0] == 'u'))
        {
            word[j] += "way";
        } else { 
            for(i = 0; i <= length-1; i++) {
                word[j][i] = word[j][i+1];
            }
            word[j][length-1] = temp[0];
            word[j] += "ay";
        }
        cout << word[j] << " ";
        length = 0;
    }
    cout << "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Did you try a debugger ?

Comment: i <= length-1, word[j][i+1] would access word[j][length], wouldn't it?

Comment: I did but cant find which line the issue is on. My guess is there is an issue with the size of temp[], but I don't know which line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement

```
temp[0] = word[j][0];
```

is invalid because string temp is empty and you may not use the subscript operator with empty strings to store a character.

You could write before the for loop for example

```
temp.resize( 1 );
```

Also I do not see any sense in the parameter temp. Instead of string temp you could use in the function local variable `char temp;` because you are using temp only to store one character.

Comment: Thank you for the string temp correction. Now i realize i can just but the first letter of from the string word into char temp and get the same result. As for the temp.resize(1); I would need to initialize a string before I can compare it?

Comment: @user3263294 If you are going to use the subscript operator then the string shall have corresponding elements. So if you for example write temp[0] then string temp shall have at least one element. The member function resize shown in my post creates such an element and initialize it with '\0'

Comment: I now understand my mistake thank you for such a quick response.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing a parameter to the ifstream: The ifstream object requires two parameters, a filename and a mode which describes the requested i/o mode for the file.

```
in.open("text.txt");
```

Should be:

```
in.open("text.txt", ifstream::in);
```

Here is a link to the API for ifstream.open:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/open/

Comment: `ifstream` does not require the second parameter, it is implicit.